# Upvotes don't reup negative reputation from downvotes after repcap achieved any more?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

[image: Major Bummer!]

As you can see, **I got downvoted**<sup>1</sup>. I then hit repcap and got upvoted a whole bunch. But I capped out at 194. As my calculations indicate, the sum of reputation lost from said downvotes is 6 and 200 - 6 = 194. Coincidence? The only other time that I can remember getting downvoted (for another stupid reason) when I had hit reputation cap, I got +2 from a future upvote. Is this a bug or has there been a change.

FWIW, I *think* that the last time this happened, I was already at repcap when I recieved the downvote. This time, I recieved all three *before* I hit repcap. Would that make a difference? If so, it seems *preeettty lame*<sup>2</sup>.

If it's a bug, then the devs should know. And if not, just disregard this. It is only six imaginary reputation points after all. I'm already 1,222 points past being able to get a 100K+ job a year without an interview.

---

**Update:** I got downvoted *again*<sup>4</sup>. And the next upvote filled in +2 like I thought that it should. Also, the vote that pushed me over repcap is showing as +7 here instead of +6 in the envelope. My reputation audit correct shows me as getting +7 for the 21'st upvote (I had made a downvote as well). So apparently, It's just the envelope that's messed up.<sup>5</sup>  Even there, It shows me getting +6 for the last vote (Something that I hadn't noticed in the sleep deprived haze in which I initially posted this.)

I got an accepted answer as well and that pushed me over the 194. However this happened after I correctly got +2 for an upvote.

I also remembered that I had deleted two answers, each of which had +1. I decided that they weren't helpful<sup>6</sup>

Here's my rep-audit as discussed. Is the amount of rep is shows as the end-of-day total what I'll have after the rep-recalc? I thought I'd lose way more from deleted answers with positive score. That's only ~500

```
 2   4261533 (10)
 3   4263256 (-1)
 3   4263495 (-2)
 2   4263495 (10)
 2   4263495 (10)
 2   4263495 (10)
 2   4263495 (10)
 2   4261533 (10)
 2   4255911 (10)
 2   4263495 (10)
 3   4263495 (-2)
 2   4265852 (10)
 2   4265852 (10)
 2   4263495 (10)
 1   4265852 (15)
 2   4266959 (10)
 2   4266959 (10)
 2   4266959 (10)
 2   4266959 (10)
 3   4266959 (-2)
 2   4266959 (10)
 2   4266959 (10)
 2   4267511 (10)
 2   4267511 (10)
 2   4267511 (10)
 2   4267511 [7]
 2   4267511 [0]
 2   4267511 [0]
 2   4267511 [0]
 2   4267511 [0]
 2   4266959 [0]
 3   4268349 [-2]
 2   4268349 [2]
 2   4267511 [0]
 1   4268349 [15]
 2   4268349 [0]
-- 2010-11-24 rep +230  = 10716
```

---

<sup>1 for two entirely stupid reasons. One person later admitted that they were wrong and the other two people have issues with at least one aspect of reality.</sup>

<sup>2 I totally understand that this is a complex system and weird bugs happen. Bugs are still lame though<sup>3</sup>. I also understand that seemingly simple things can actually be extraordinarily complex to the point that they're not worth doing. If that's the case, it's lame too. I guess what I'm trying to say is, however you cut it, this is lame. Though possible with good reason for being so.</sup>

<sup>3 Unless they have six legs in which case they're awesome</sup>

<sup>4 I swear I almost never get downvoted: This time, I *think* I did deserve it although no message was left.</sup>

<sup>5 Thanks to Grace Note for pointing that this should be looked at.</sup>

<sup>6 One was to a question with terrible english that was later clarified and one was a snarky reminder that every number in sight is rational when you're a programmer.</sup>

Comment: Can you check your [reputation audit](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and see what the report for 11/24/2010 is? Among other things, you have an accepted answer for 15 points, which is immune to the cap, yet your report is showing <200. So, there's something odd in your envelope, in which case getting the accurate report from your audit will be more valuable.

Comment: Same for me. The day-to-day summary audit no longer allows upvotes to make up for downvotes. All is well in the "official" reputation audit where an upvote can make up for downvotes up to the level of the cap.

Comment: +1 for freehand circles.